# Question mark in Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm. When I try to use the question mark '?' to get documentation (which works fine when I use it in the browser), it returns [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhPRt.png) in Pycharm.

Would anybody know how I could make this work in Pycharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to use help instead of ?. ? also doesn't work for me when using jupyter notebook in pycharm. But help does.

Example:

```
help(set)
```

Prints out

```
Help on class set in module builtins.
class set(object)
 |  set() -> new empty set object
 |  set(iterable) -> new set object
 |  
 |  Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:...
```